# Using fingerprint with flutter in the web environment

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web, fingerprint

I'm using local_auth in Flutter, but local_auth doesn't support web.
I need that if a user logs into the web version of my app with their mobile, they can log in with their fingerprint.
I also wrote the web version with Flutter.

What should I do to solve this problem?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.